# Meta Programming - dynamic method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 versions of Computer class here. I'm seeing that Computer2 is much better than Computer1. Both Computer classes yield the same result. How the Computer2 class varies from Computer1 class?

```
class DataSource
  def cpu_info(computer_id)
    "#{computer_id}'s CPU"
  end

  def cpu_price(computer_id)
    12
  end

  def mouse_info(computer_id)
    "#{computer_id}'s mouse"
  end

  def mouse_price(computer_id)
    27
  end

  def monitor_info(computer_id)
    "#{computer_id}'s monitor"
  end

  def monitor_price(computer_id)
    33
  end
end

# Step 1
class Computer1
  def initialize(computer_id, data_source)
    @id = computer_id
    @ds = data_source
  end

  def cpu
    get_info :cpu
  end

  def mouse
    get_info :mouse
  end

  def monitor
    get_info :monitor
  end

  def get_info(component)
    component_info = @ds.send("#{component}_info", @id)
    component_price = @ds.send("#{component}_price", @id)
    data = "The work station #{component_info} is about #{component_price}$"
    return data;
  end
end

computer = Computer1.new(1, DataSource.new)
computer.cpu #The work station 1's CPU is about 12$

# Step 2 - Further simplified
class Computer2
  def initialize(computer_id, data_source)
    @id = computer_id
    @ds = data_source
  end

  def self.get_info(component)
    define_method(component) do
      component_info = @ds.send("#{component}_info", @id)
      component_price = @ds.send("#{component}_price", @id)
      data = "The work station #{component_info} is about #{component_price}$"
      return data;
    end
  end

  get_info :mouse
  get_info :cpu
  get_info :monitor
end

computer = Computer2.new(1, DataSource.new)
computer.cpu #The work station 1's CPU is about 12$
```

My question is how the following is possible as there is no instance cpu method in Computer2 class

```
computer = Computer2.new(1, DataSource.new)
computer.cpu
```

Answer (score 1):

When your class `Computer2` is loaded, self calls `get_info` class method with argument `:cpu` which is later used to define instance method `cpu` for your Computer2 instance.

Read [define_method](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method)

Answer (score 1):

In the Computer2 class, you call the method :get_info:

```
get_info :mouse
get_info :cpu
get_info :monitor
```

This methods, call the ruby function :define_method (https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method), this method creates a named function for you instance in this case, and after call `get_info(:cpu)` you have the `.cpu` method to call, with the giving block:

```
component_info = @ds.send("#{component}_info", @id)
component_price = @ds.send("#{component}_price", @id)
data = "The work station #{component_info} is about #{component_price}$"
return data;
```